# Mount QNX filesystem in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: partitioning, kernel, mount, filesystem

I am trying to mount QNX6 filesystem in Ubuntu 18.04.

For that I searched and found that I have to recompile my Linux kernel and enable CONFIG_QNX6FS_FS which I did and recompiled my kernel and all the modules are successfully installed. Output of the following command is `uname -mrs` is `Linux 5.1.8 x86_64`.

When I tried to make a partition in a new hard-drive using `mkfs -t qnx6 -L /qnx6 -v /dev/sdb`, it said `mkfs: failed to execute mkfs.qnx6: No such file or directory`.

Please suggest a solution to mount QNX6 filesystem on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel only covers the kernel, mkfs.qnx6 is helper userspace utility you are missing. Likely need to be build and installed from mkfs sources?